# Modified WFS feature was not saved in Database

Tags: gis, postgis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I managed to load the WFS and my basemap successfully and managed to get the buttons to show up. The buttons appear correctly like in the working example, for some reason the geometry data isn't being saved. Delete button is working fine (whenever I delete a polygon it is deleted and also in the GeoServer published layer) but editing was not working fine.

i.e. I am able to edit the polygon or line, but it is not saved and whenever I refresh the page it is showing the previous polygon not the edited one.

The bit of my code for posting is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

            var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
            
            featureNS: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/Peru',
            featureType: 'Buildings',
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
        });


        var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
            //format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({ extractGeometryName: true }),
            url: function (extent) {
                return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                    'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=Peru:Buildings&' +
                    'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
                    'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
            projection: proj
        });

        window.loadFeatures = function (response) {
            vectorSource.addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response));
        };

        var vectorLayerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: sourceWFS
        });

        var interaction;
   
        var interactionSelectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
            condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
        });
        var interactionSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#FF2828'
                })
            })
        });
        var interactionSnap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
            source: vectorLayerWFS.getSource()
        });

        var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });
        var proj = 'EPSG:4326';
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [raster, vectorLayerWFS],
            target: document.getElementById('map'),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([74.2543165420606, 22.844272350403696], 'EPSG:4326', proj),
                maxZoom: 19,
                zoom: 14,
                projection: proj
            })
        });

        //wfs-t
        var dirty = {};
        var transactWFS = function (mode, f) {
            var node;

            function removeNodeForWfsUpdate(node, valueToRemove) {
                var propNodes = node.getElementsByTagName("Property");
                for (var i = 0; i < propNodes.length; i++) {
                    var propNode = propNodes[i];
                    var propNameNode = propNode.firstElementChild;
                    var propNameNodeValue = propNameNode.firstChild;
                    if (propNameNodeValue.nodeValue === valueToRemove) {
                        propNode.parentNode.removeChild(propNode);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            switch (mode) {
            
                case 'update':
                    // Update Parameter for new GEOMETRY NODE
                    f.set('geometry', f.getGeometry());
                    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
                    // Remove lower case geometry node which will cause update to fail
                    removeNodeForWfsUpdate(node, "geometry");

                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
                    break;
            }
            var xs = new XMLSerializer();
            var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);

            console.log(payload);

            $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Peru/wfs',
                {
                    service: 'WFS',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: 'text/xml',
                    data: payload,
                    error: function (e) {
                        var errorMsg = e ? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
                        alert('Error saving this feature to GeoServer. \n\n'
                            + errorMsg);
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(data));
                    sourceWFS.clear();

                });
        };

        $('button').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('btn-active');
            $(this).addClass('btn-active');
            map.removeInteraction(interaction);
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().clear();
            map.removeInteraction(interactionSelect);

            switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
                case 'btnEdit':
                    map.addInteraction(interactionSelect);
                    interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                        features: interactionSelect.getFeatures()
                    });
                    map.addInteraction(interaction);
                    map.addInteraction(interactionSnap);
                    dirty = {};
                    interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                        e.element.on('change', function (e) {
                            dirty[e.target.getId()] = true;
                        });
                    });
                    interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('remove', function (e) {
                        var f = e.element;
                        if (dirty[f.getId()]) {
                            delete dirty[f.getId()];
                            var featureProperties = f.getProperties();
                            delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
                            var clone = new ol.Feature(featureProperties);
                            clone.setId(f.getId());
                            transactWFS('update', clone);
                        }
                    });
                    break;

                case 'btnDelete':
                    interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
                    interaction.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                        transactWFS('delete', e.target.item(0));
                        interactionSelectPointerMove.getFeatures().clear();
                        interaction.getFeatures().clear();
                    });
                    map.addInteraction(interaction);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The XML request that I have sent:

```
<Transaction
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <Update typeName="feature:Buildings"
        xmlns:feature="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/Peru">
        <Property>
            <Name>OBJECTID</Name>
            <Value>21348</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>BUILDINGNA</Name>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>BUILDINGAD</Name>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>SHAPE_Leng</Name>
            <Value>70.10207871120306</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>SHAPE_Area</Name>
            <Value>272.00550843505323</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>height</Name>
            <Value>7000</Value>
        </Property>
        <Filter
            xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <FeatureId fid="Buildings.21342"/>
        </Filter>
    </Update>
</Transaction>
```

The Response that I have got is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:TransactionResponse
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:TransactionSummary>
        <wfs:totalInserted>0</wfs:totalInserted>
        <wfs:totalUpdated>1</wfs:totalUpdated>
        <wfs:totalDeleted>0</wfs:totalDeleted>
    </wfs:TransactionSummary>
    <wfs:TransactionResults/>
    <wfs:InsertResults>
        <wfs:Feature>
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="none"/>
        </wfs:Feature>
    </wfs:InsertResults>
</wfs:TransactionResponse>
```

The Geoserver log:

```
    2021-10-12 16:18:19,823 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[74.22285959473393 : 74.28577348938725, 22.812085842224985 : 22.876458858582406] ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {Peru}Buildings
    outputFormat = application/json
    resultType = results
2021-10-12 16:18:19,826 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2021-10-12 16:18:19,828 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:19,841 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-10-12 16:18:19,850 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:19,851 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:19,853 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-10-12 16:18:19,853 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((74.22285959473393 22.812085842224985, 74.22285959473393 22.876458858582406, 74.28577348938725 22.876458858582406, 74.28577348938725 22.812085842224985, 74.22285959473393 22.812085842224985))', 4326)
2021-10-12 16:18:19,866 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:19,867 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:19,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-10-12 16:18:19,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:19,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:19,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-10-12 16:18:19,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "gid","OBJECTID","BUILDINGNA","BUILDINGAD","SHAPE_Leng","SHAPE_Area",encode(ST_AsEWKB("geom"), 'base64') as "geom","height" FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((74.22285959473393 22.812085842224985, 74.22285959473393 22.876458858582406, 74.28577348938725 22.876458858582406, 74.28577348938725 22.812085842224985, 74.22285959473393 22.812085842224985))', 4326) LIMIT 1000000
2021-10-12 16:18:22,750 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:25,926 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-10-12 16:18:25,929 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[74.22446176671238 : 74.2873756613657, 22.807794307801156 : 22.87216732415858] ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {Peru}Buildings
    outputFormat = application/json
    resultType = results
2021-10-12 16:18:25,930 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2021-10-12 16:18:25,930 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:25,933 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-10-12 16:18:25,933 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:25,933 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:25,933 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-10-12 16:18:25,933 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((74.22446176671238 22.807794307801156, 74.22446176671238 22.87216732415858, 74.2873756613657 22.87216732415858, 74.2873756613657 22.807794307801156, 74.22446176671238 22.807794307801156))', 4326)
2021-10-12 16:18:25,940 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:25,941 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:25,944 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-10-12 16:18:25,944 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:25,944 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:25,944 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-10-12 16:18:25,944 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "gid","OBJECTID","BUILDINGNA","BUILDINGAD","SHAPE_Leng","SHAPE_Area",encode(ST_AsEWKB("geom"), 'base64') as "geom","height" FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((74.22446176671238 22.807794307801156, 74.22446176671238 22.87216732415858, 74.2873756613657 22.87216732415858, 74.2873756613657 22.807794307801156, 74.22446176671238 22.807794307801156))', 4326) LIMIT 1000000
2021-10-12 16:18:28,726 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:47,474 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-10-12 16:18:47,482 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd
2021-10-12 16:18:47,484 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/wfs: http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-9.0.44/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.19.2.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
2021-10-12 16:18:47,490 INFO [org.geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: {Peru}Buildings TransactionEventType[PreUpdate]
2021-10-12 16:18:47,491 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (GeometryFactory, JTS_GEOMETRY_FACTORY)
2021-10-12 16:18:47,492 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (GeometryFactory, JTS_GEOMETRY_FACTORY): found implementation Optional.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,492 TRACE [org.geotools.util] - Error applying the converter class org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1 on (LayerInfoImpl-71cfc207:17bbec7e592:-7ffd,class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)
org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException: Unknown geometry type: LayerInfoImpl-71cfc207
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.readGeometryTaggedText(WKTReader2.java:401)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:139)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:112)
    at org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1.convert(GeometryConverterFactory.java:56)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:150)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:117)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.getGeometries(GeometryFilterImpl.java:113)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.evaluate(GeometryFilterImpl.java:203)
    at org.geotools.filter.OrImpl.evaluate(OrImpl.java:33)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.lambda$toPredicate$23(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:1133)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogInfoLookup.list(CatalogInfoLookup.java:148)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.iterable(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:1104)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.list(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:1073)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.IsolatedCatalogFacade.list(IsolatedCatalogFacade.java:511)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor296.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.LockingCatalogFacade.invoke(LockingCatalogFacade.java:36)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.list(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.list(CatalogImpl.java:2065)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.list(SecureCatalogImpl.java:1468)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AbstractFilteredCatalog.list(AbstractFilteredCatalog.java:771)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog.list(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:534)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog.list(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:515)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWC.getTileLayersByFeatureType(GWC.java:1515)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWCTransactionListener.dataStoreChangeInternal(GWCTransactionListener.java:197)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWCTransactionListener.dataStoreChange(GWCTransactionListener.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction$TransactionListenerMux.dataStoreChange(Transaction.java:619)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction$TransactionListenerMux.dataStoreChange(Transaction.java:624)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.UpdateElementHandler.execute(UpdateElementHandler.java:307)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:297)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor410.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)



    2021-10-12 16:18:47,495 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,495 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,495 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (GeometryFactory, JTS_GEOMETRY_FACTORY)
2021-10-12 16:18:47,496 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (GeometryFactory, JTS_GEOMETRY_FACTORY): found implementation Optional.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,496 TRACE [org.geotools.util] - Error applying the converter class org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1 on (LayerInfoImpl-71cfc207:17bbec7e592:-7ffd,class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)
org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException: Unknown geometry type: LayerInfoImpl-71cfc207
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.readGeometryTaggedText(WKTReader2.java:401)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:139)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:112)
    at org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1.convert(GeometryConverterFactory.java:56)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:150)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:117)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.getGeometries(GeometryFilterImpl.java:113)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.evaluate(GeometryFilterImpl.java:203)
    at org.geotools.filter.OrImpl.evaluate(OrImpl.java:33)

    2021-10-12 16:18:47,501 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,501 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,501 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:47,503 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - Exporting FID=[Buildings.24038]
2021-10-12 16:18:47,503 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - Retrieving bounding box: SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Force2D(ST_Envelope(ST_Extent("geom"::geometry)))) FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE ("gid" = '24038')
2021-10-12 16:18:47,507 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - Exporting FID=[Buildings.24038]
2021-10-12 16:18:47,507 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "gid","OBJECTID","BUILDINGNA","BUILDINGAD","SHAPE_Leng","SHAPE_Area",encode(ST_AsEWKB("geom"), 'base64') as "geom","height" FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE ("gid" = '24038')
2021-10-12 16:18:47,510 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:47,510 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:47,510 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:47,510 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:47,510 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:47,510 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:47,511 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - Exporting FID=[Buildings.24038]
2021-10-12 16:18:47,511 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - Updating feature: UPDATE "public"."Buildings" SET "OBJECTID" = 24044.0,"BUILDINGNA" = NULL,"BUILDINGAD" = NULL,"SHAPE_Leng" = 50.691807301866305,"SHAPE_Area" = 160.5821877944448,"height" = '7000'  WHERE ("gid" = '24038')
2021-10-12 16:18:47,533 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - Exporting FID=[Buildings.24038]
2021-10-12 16:18:47,533 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "gid","OBJECTID","BUILDINGNA","BUILDINGAD","SHAPE_Leng","SHAPE_Area",encode(ST_AsEWKB("geom"), 'base64') as "geom","height" FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE ("gid" = '24038')
2021-10-12 16:18:47,536 INFO [org.geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: {Peru}Buildings TransactionEventType[PostUpdate]
2021-10-12 16:18:47,538 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - ENTRY  (GeometryFactory, JTS_GEOMETRY_FACTORY)
2021-10-12 16:18:47,538 TRACE [org.geotools.util.factory] - RETURN (GeometryFactory, JTS_GEOMETRY_FACTORY): found implementation Optional.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,538 TRACE [org.geotools.util] - Error applying the converter class org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1 on (LayerInfoImpl-71cfc207:17bbec7e592:-7ffd,class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)
org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException: Unknown geometry type: LayerInfoImpl-71cfc207
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.readGeometryTaggedText(WKTReader2.java:401)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:139)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:112)
    at org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1.convert(GeometryConverterFactory.java:56)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:150)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:117)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.getGeometries(GeometryFilterImpl.java:113)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.evaluate(GeometryFilterImpl.java:203)
    at org.geotools.filter.OrImpl.evaluate(OrImpl.java:33)

    2021-10-12 16:18:47,546 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,546 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,546 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - Exporting FID=[Buildings.24038]
2021-10-12 16:18:47,546 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - Retrieving bounding box: SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Force2D(ST_Envelope(ST_Extent("geom"::geometry)))) FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE ("gid" = '24038')
2021-10-12 16:18:47,571 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:47,571 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:update=net.opengis.wfs.impl.UpdateElementTypeImpl@61f135d7 (filter: [ Buildings.24038 ], handle: null, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null, typeName: {Peru}Buildings)
    update[0]:
        property[0]:
            name = OBJECTID
            value = 24044property[0]:
            name = BUILDINGNAproperty[0]:
            name = BUILDINGADproperty[0]:
            name = SHAPE_Leng
            value = 50.691807301866305property[0]:
            name = SHAPE_Area
            value = 160.5821877944448property[0]:
            name = height
            value = 7000
        filter = [ Buildings.24038 ]
        inputFormat = x-application/gml:3
        typeName = {Peru}Buildings
    releaseAction = ALL
2021-10-12 16:18:47,571 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:47,571 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-10-12 16:18:48,063 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-10-12 16:18:48,066 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[74.25831455878705 : 74.26617879561871, 22.81668362708342 : 22.8247302541281] ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {Peru}Buildings
    outputFormat = application/json
    resultType = results
2021-10-12 16:18:48,067 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2021-10-12 16:18:48,067 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:48,129 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-10-12 16:18:48,129 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:48,130 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:48,130 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-10-12 16:18:48,130 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((74.25831455878705 22.81668362708342, 74.25831455878705 22.8247302541281, 74.26617879561871 22.8247302541281, 74.26617879561871 22.81668362708342, 74.25831455878705 22.81668362708342))', 4326)
2021-10-12 16:18:48,276 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:48,277 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-10-12 16:18:48,283 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-10-12 16:18:48,283 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
2021-10-12 16:18:48,283 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-10-12 16:18:48,284 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-10-12 16:18:48,286 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "gid","OBJECTID","BUILDINGNA","BUILDINGAD","SHAPE_Leng","SHAPE_Area",encode(ST_AsEWKB("geom"), 'base64') as "geom","height" FROM "public"."Buildings" WHERE "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((74.25831455878705 22.81668362708342, 74.25831455878705 22.8247302541281, 74.26617879561871 22.8247302541281, 74.26617879561871 22.81668362708342, 74.25831455878705 22.81668362708342))', 4326) LIMIT 1000000
2021-10-12 16:18:48,394 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I have updated the geoserver log.

Comment: there is still no error in the log - try at GEOTOOLS-DEVEL level, you should see the actual SQL query that will be used

Comment: I have updated the GEOTOOLS-DEVELOPERS logs.

Comment: So, GeoServer is unable to parse your geometry element which makes sense as it is missing from your transaction

Comment: So, this means that the data which we are passing is not in the right format and need to fix the request payload..?

Comment: no, it means you don't send a geometry - `removeNodeForWfsUpdate(node, "geometry");` looks suspicious to me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.